# Where is issue with final display in this code?

Tags: python-3.x

The code requires the user to provide an input of strings and convert the uppercase to lower and vice-versa.Input: Rohit Tapadia  , Expected Output: rOHIT tAPADIA , Actual Output: rOHIt TAPADIA . It should do exactly what the swapcase() does.

````
    inp = input("Enter  ")
    for i in inp:
        inp_lst.append(i)
    print(inp_lst)
    for j in inp_lst:
        if j.isupper()==True:
            x=inp_lst.index(j)
            #print(x)
            #print(j)
            k = j.lower()
            #print(k)
            inp_lst[x]=k
            print(inp_lst[x])
        elif j.islower()==True:
            y=inp_lst.index(j)
            #print(y)
            #print(j)
            l = j.upper()
            inp_lst[y]=l
            print(inp_lst[y])
        else:
            z=inp_lst.index(j)
            #print(z)
            #print(j)
            inp_lst[z]=j
            print(inp_lst[z])
        print(''.join(inp_lst))```
````

Comment: Is the output below is the one you are expecting
`Enter abCD
['a', 'b', 'C', 'D']
0
a
A
AbCD
1
b
B
ABCD
2
C
c
ABcD
3
D
d
ABcd`

Comment: I encourage the OP to include explicit example of input that produces undesirable output.

Comment: Please include the output of your code as well as the desired output.

Comment: @glhr   Input: Rohit Tapadia  , Expected Output: rOHIT tAPADIA , Actual Output: rOHIt TAPADIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve exactly the same thing in 2 lines with the built-in [`swapcase()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html):

```
inp = input("Enter  ")
print(inp.swapcase())
```

Example input:

```
heLLo StackOverflow
```

Output:

```
HEllO sTACKoVERFLOW
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55548482

Edit: here's a working and simplified implementation of your code. Note that `inp_lst` is not needed since you can directly iterate over characters in a string. You can simply add each character to the output string using string concatenation (not that `outputString += j` is equivalent to `outputString = outputString + j` - it simply adds `j` at the end of the string).

```
inp = input("Enter  ")
outputString = ""
for j in inp:
    if j.isupper():
            outputString += j.lower()
    elif j.islower():
            outputString += j.upper()
    else:
            outputString += j
print(outputString)
```

Edit 2: The problem in your code is this  `inp_lst.index(j)`, because `index()` searches for the first occurrence of the character `j`. So if `j='t'`, it will select the first occurrence of `t` in the list, and turn it uppercase/lowercase, even if the loop is at the second occurrence of `t`. That's why the first `t` in `"Rohit Tapadia"` is turned to lowercase in the output.

Comment: Yes, but I want to generate a function by myself that does it. So above is the block of code inside that function. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Thanks @glhr. Its simple and elegant! :)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this one too

```
inp = input("Enter  ")
output="".join([char.lower() if  char.isupper() else char.upper() for char in inp ])
```

`inp = "Rohit Tapadia"`

output will be

`rOHIT tAPADIA`